# Groups that don't contain quasi-hyperbolic plane

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

Is there any known example of a one-ended finitely presented group with exponential growth that does not contain a quasi-isometric copy of the hyperbolic plane?

This question is motivated by the following question of Papasoglu mentioned in the paper  *'Quasi-hyperbolic planes in hyperbolic group'* by Bonk–Kleiner which asks whether every one-ended finitely presented group $G$ contains a quasi plane- the image of a uniform embedding $P\rightarrow G$ where $P$ is a complete Riemannian plane with bounded geometry.

Thank you for reading this.

Comment: I don't know. It's true for polycyclic groups and Baumslag-Solitar groups $\mathrm{BS}(m,n)$ for $0<m<n$. However I'm not sure for $\mathbf{F}_2\times\mathbf{Z}$.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you please give me a reference or any insights about why it is true for any  polycyclic group with exponential growth?

Comment: For polycyclic groups I just checked it, I don't think it's written. A polycyclic group of exp. growth is QI to some real triangulable Lie group. And the latter contains a QI-embedded 2-dimensional affine group $\mathbf{R}\rtimes\mathbf{R}$.

Comment: And I tend to believe that $F_2\times\mathbf{Z}$ has no QI-embedded $\mathbf{H}^2$. Intuitively the QI-embedded planes therein should be Euclidean.

Comment: Maybe this is trivial but can I ask why that QI-embedded 2-dimensional affine group obstruct QI-embedding of the hyperbolic plane?

Comment: It's not an obstruction... at the opposite, it's equivalent.

Comment: Oh, I guess I misunderstood. So, at the beginning when you said 'It's true for polycyclic groups....' you meant they actually do contain quasi- hyperbolic plane as long as the growth is exponential.

Comment: Oops, sorry. I'm often confused by questions that are asked in the negative.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much for your answers though. It was very helpful. I also think $F_2\times Z$ does not contain quasi-hyperbolic plane. Probably, because if there was such embedding, the induced map on the boundary circle should be injective,  in particular the image would be a circle. Now, each circle in the boundary of $F_2\times Z$ comes from a 'unique' Euclidean plane inside $F_2\times Z$. And so the quasi-isometry has to map the hyperbolic plane to that Euclidean plane which is absurd.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a result of Buyalo and Schroeder [BS, Corollary 1.2] that for every $n\ge 2$ there is no QI embedding of the hyperbolic space $\mathbb{H}^n_\mathbf{R}$ into any product of $n-1$ trees with a Euclidean space.

In particular, the 1-ended group $F_2\times\mathbf{Z}$ (as well as $F_2\times\mathbf{Z}^d$ for arbitrary $d\ge 1$) contains no QI-copy of the hyperbolic plane, thus answering your question.

[BS] S. Buyalo and V. Schroeder. The hyperbolic dimension of metric spaces. Algebra i Analiz, 19(1):93–108, 2007. [ArXiv link](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0404525)